# how can i know if a table of a database have a new registre?

Tags: sql, database, backend, data-capture

My goal is to be able to know in real time or close to real time if a new record has been entered in a database or not.

Is it possible to do this or is the only way to poll the table every X seconds to see if anything has changed?

Would polling a table too often to see if a table insert has occurred be bad practice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you can try to use triggers

In mysql for example

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).